# Help trying to show that $p_0a_1 =0$

Tags: integration, sp.spectral-theory, banach-algebras

> Let $A$ be a Banach algebra and let $\Gamma_0, \Gamma_1$ be circles of centres 0 and 1 respectively, each of radius less that $\frac{1}{2}$, which bound the two open disks $\Delta_0$ and $\Delta_1$.
>
> Furthermore, let $a \in A$ with $\text{Sp}(a)=\{0,1\}$. Here $\text{Sp}(a)$ denotes the spectrum of $a$ in $A$.
>
> Define $$p_0 = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\Gamma_0}(\lambda-a)^{-1}d\lambda$$ and $$a_1 = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\Gamma_1}\lambda(\lambda -a)^{-1}d\lambda.$$

I am now trying to show that $p_0a_1=0$.

I have the following so far:

Let $\lambda\neq \mu$ not be in $\text{Sp}(a)$, then:
\begin{align*}
p_0a_1 &= \bigg[\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\Gamma_0}(\lambda-a)^{-1}d\lambda\bigg]\bigg[ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\Gamma_1}\mu(\mu -a)^{-1}d\mu \bigg] \\
&= -\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_{\Gamma_0}(\lambda-a)^{-1}d\lambda \cdot \int_{\Gamma_1}\mu(\mu -a)^{-1}d\mu \\
&= -\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_{\Gamma_0}\int_{\Gamma_1}\mu(\lambda -a)^{-1}(\mu-a)^{-1}d\mu d\lambda \\
&= -\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_{\Gamma_0}\int_{\Gamma_1}\mu\bigg[\frac{(\lambda-a)^{-1} - (\mu-a)^{-1}}{\mu - \lambda} \bigg]d \mu \lambda \\
&= -\frac{1}{4\pi^2} \bigg[ \int_{\Gamma_0}\int_{\Gamma_1}\mu\frac{(\lambda-a)^{-1}}{\mu - \lambda}d\mu d\lambda - \int_{\Gamma_0}\int_{\Gamma_1}\mu\frac{(\mu-a)^{-1}}{\mu-\lambda}d\mu d\lambda \bigg]
\end{align*}

However, this is where I am stuck... Can anyone please help guide me on the right direction to showing that the above equates to zero?

Comment: This looks like an exercise problem to me.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy . This isn't an exercise problem. I am working though the paper "Spectrum-preserving linear mappings between Banach algebra and Jordan-Banach algebras" (https://academic.oup.com/jlms/article-abstract/62/3/917/874307/Spectrum-Preserving-Linear-Mappings-between-Banach?redirectedFrom=PDF) by Aupetit. In his proof of Theorem 1.1 (ii) he defines these two (and two other) mappings and then states that $p_0a= a_0$. I am trying to see why this is true, but in order to do so, I needed the result in my question.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy  According to  conversations on [this meta  post](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3255/newbie-style-questions-is-there-an-official-viewpoint-of-mo), is  not  a  good  idea that this  question would be  reopen (Would not be    on Hold)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply  [holomorphic  functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus)  to  the  following  functions which are  defined  on a disconnected open set in the  plane  containing $\Gamma_0 , \Gamma_1$

$f(z)=\begin{cases} 1&  \text{Around 0}\\0&  \text{around 1}\end{cases}$

$g(z)=\begin{cases} 0&  \text{Around 0}\\z&  \text{around 1}\end{cases}$

Then $p_0=f(a), a_1=g(a)$  but $fg=0$.

By the  same  argument one can shows that $p_0a=a_0$  where

$$a_0 = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\Gamma_0}\lambda(\lambda -a)^{-1}d\lambda.$$

Comment: Wow! This simplifies the argument significantly! This also makes is super trivial to show that $p_0$ and $p_1$ are idempotents! Thank you for this.

Comment: @user290425  You are well come.